# Unable to run Mongod command after installing MongoDB and adding to environment variables

Tags: windows, mongodb, command-line

I've added the following path to Environment Variables but I still can't run the Mongo commands, i.e. mongod, mongo --version.

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\
```

Comment: it would be helpful to understand what error message you received

Comment: Since this is a Windows installation can you confirm the mongod service is running?